# SwiftUI UIKit data update working for new projects but same code not working for existing project

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI view

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {    
        @State var list = [1,2,3,4]
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button("Click Me") {
                    list.append(list.last! + 1)
                    print(list)
                }
                List {
                    ForEach(list , id : \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have loaded that code inside my project using UIHostViewcontroller.

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let contentViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(contentViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

The list not updating when tapped on button and I have created new project with UIKit and loaded same ContentView from FirstViewController it's working fine, But I don't know what's wrong with existing projects.

Comment: It might be hard to help if the behavior can not  be reproduced

Comment: any wild guess for reason ?

Comment: It seams it's state change issue , because when clicks on button that action is executing but new element is not added to array , when it came to brand new project it's working fine